# BATCH Opening Location

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a question
set the opening location of a batch file

```
@echo off
Mode 15,3 & color a
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
test.bat
exit
```

Is it possible to run the test.bat file in the following location?

```
x=720 , y=720
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... It is not possible to control the position of the command window by any standard method provided by cmd.exe or any of the standard Windows command-line commands.

But, you can use a programming language to write a small program that moves the window to that position and run that program as part of your bat-file.
The AutoIt scripting language is very often used for this sort of thing. But it is also possible in PowerShell if you want to stick with Windows build-in components.

Comment: Not completely correct as you can specify the default size and location for a command shell in its properties.

Comment: @DavidPostill *you can specify the default size and location for a command shell in its properties* It is shortcut settings, not command shell settings. We don't know how this batch is started - maybe via `Win-R` - `test.bat<Enter>`...

Comment: @Akina No it's not. Open a cmd shell, click on the top left icon, then defaults, then layout. That sets the default properties for all cmd windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill *That sets the default properties for all cmd windows.* That's right... but where they are stored?

Comment: @Akina In the registry somewhere?

Comment: @DavidPostill No. Open cmd window from main menu shortcut. Adjust its position as you describe. Close it. Then open cmd via `win-r` - your adjust is lost... adjust this windows with other settings than first one. Close it. Open using 1st method. 1st adjusting applied. Different methods - different shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a small VB Script to open the bat file.
Use file extension .vbs and place the VB Script in the same folder as the bat file.

```vb
'Application
'vbScript to open bat file prompt in wanted position
'Use file extension .vbs
'Place the VB Script in the same folder as the bat file
'COMMENT
'config X, Y and batfilename
    
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objConfig = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
objConfig.SpawnInstance_

objConfig.X = 720
objConfig.Y = 720
batfilename="test.bat"
    
path= Mid(WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, (Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName)))
Set objNewProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
intReturn = objNewProcess.Create(path+""+batfilename, Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

Comment: win11 not work, open in default pos